# Setting up pipelines reading from named pipes without blocking in bash

Tags: bash, unix, shell, pipe

I'm looking to call a subprocess with a file descriptor opened to a given pipe such that the open() call does not hang waiting for the other side of the pipe to receive a connection.

To demonstrate:

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/foobar.pipe
$ some_program --command-fd=5 5</tmp/foobar.pipe
```

In this case, `some_program` is not run until some process has `/tmp/foobar.pipe` open for write; however, `some_program` has useful effects even when it isn't receiving commands, so desired behavior is for `some_program` to be immediately executed.

Mechanisms to do this by exec'ing through an alternate scripting language (python, perl, etc) or a C wrapper which open `/tmp/foobar.pipe` with the `O_NONBLOCK` flag are obvious; I'm looking for a pure-bash solution, should one be possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Opening the FD read/write rather than read-only when setting up the pipeline prevents blocking.

To be a bit more specific:

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/foobar.pipe
$ some_program --command-fd=5 5<>/tmp/foobar.pipe
```

prevents the undesired blocking behavior, as `5<>/tmp/foobar.pipe` opens in RW mode (as opposed to opening in read-only mode as with `5</tmp/foobar.pipe`) although `O_NONBLOCK` is still set. Thanks to waldner on irc://irc.freenode.org/#bash for this pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know getting this kind of result is a hack:

```
mkfifo /tmp/foobar.in
mkfifo /tmp/foobar.out
( cat </tmp/foobar.in ) >/tmp/foobar.out &
some_program --command-fd=5 5</tmp/foobar.out
```

perhaps this helps :-)

Comment: you're right it was a typo. just edited it. And yes the background process is ugly, this is why I called it a hack :)