# How to flush a pipe using bash

Tags: bash, named-pipes

I have a script that writes to a named pipe and another that reads from the pipe.  Occasionally, when starting the script I have noticed that the contents of the pipe exist from a previous run of the script.  Is there a way to flush out the pipe at the beginning of the script?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think `dd` is your friend:

```
dd if=myfifo iflag=nonblock of=/dev/null
```

strace shows

```
open("myfifo", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)
```

and indeed doesn't even block on an empty fifo.

Comment: confused, this is not bash is it?

Comment: Not in the sense of using bash-builtin commands/features, but definitely in the sense of a shell scripting solution using standard unix tools.

Answer (score 2):

You can read from the pipe until it is empty.  This will effectively flush it.

Before you attempt this daring feat, call `fcntl(mypipe, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK)` (I don't know the shell-scripting equivalent) to make a read when the pipe is empty not hang your program.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

"Opening the FD read/write rather than read-only when setting up the pipeline prevents blocking."

from:

[Setting up pipelines reading from named pipes without blocking in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179291/setting-up-pipelines-reading-from-named-pipes-without-blocking-in-bash)