# Not able to echo prstat -a command

Tags: shell

I am trying to echo the command `prstat -a` as below, but it is not working.

Is it because the output is not static or is there another reason?

Here is the command I am using:

```
echo"$(prstat -a)"
```

Comment: Try with a space between `o` and `"`, `echo "$(prstat -a)"`. `But it is not working.` - this is a very vague description. What does that mean? Do you get an error? Something happens? What happens? How do you differentiatte the "is not working" state from working state? What did you expect? What did you get? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I guess "the proper command" is just `prstat -a`.

Comment: Hi Kamil.  Thanks for your reply.  I am preparing shell scripting for few commands. This process statistics is one of the command.  I am not getting any error when i enter the command echo "$(prstat -a) ". It got stuck,  not giving any o/p. I want to put this command (prstat -a) in my script.  So i am checking that using echo.

Comment: `not giving any o/p` - what is "o/p"? It just gets stuck? Is there any output? For how long? Does just running `prstat -a` without command substitution get's stuck? For how long? How long does it take for prstat command to execute? `time prstat -a` ? I believe the prstat runs forever and never exits. So I guess you need to specify the count or do you want to ouptut the variable in real time? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5166/prstat-1m/index.html ` By default, prstat reports statistics until a termination signal is received.`

Comment: Yes, I want to output the variable in real time. You are correct. The prstat runs forever and never exit until there is a termination signal.

Comment: Ooooch, ok. That changes things. Hm...

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, I want to output the variable in real time.

Then you have to buffer the output of the command somewhere. You can do that with a fifo. Redirect the output of the command to a fifo and output it. You could also output the command to a file, but it would grow indifnitely. Note, that reading from a fifo is a blocking operations. Note that writing to a fifo if no process is listening is also blocking.

The following script is only a starting point. You would need to add some locking on the fifo accesses, buffer the command output, specify some buffer maximum size, etc. etc. Comments in code.

```
# create a temporary fifo
tmp=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo "$tmp"
# now we start the prstat command _in the background_
# the output of the command will go into fifo file
# to be safe, we close stdin
prstat > "$tmp" < /dev/null &
prstat_pid=$!
# to be sure everything is fine, remember to pick out the trash
# kill prstat after your script exists
# remove the remporary fifo after your script exists
trap_exit() { 
   if kill -0 "$prstat_pid"; then
       kill "$prstat_pid"
   fi
   rm -r "$tmp"
}
trap 'trap_exit' EXIT

# ok now, your work here
echo "some work"
# now you can read from the fifo
# note that reading on a fifo will _block_ your script
# so you have to use a timeout or something
# otherwise you will be blocked forever
timeout 0.1 cat "$tmp"
# continue with your work
echo "some other work"
```

Comment: If you have bash, you could also do a shell redirection with eval, without the need for  a temporary file. Like `eval 10<> <(prstat)` and then use `cat <&10` to read from the 10th file descriptor (but... there are problems with killing `prstat` after your script exists, so I don't think I would recommend that...). There are even more tricks, ex like `dd if=myfifo iflag=nonblock of=/dev/stdin` could work better/faster then naive `timeout cat`, from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348614/how-to-flush-a-pipe-using-bash).

Answer (score 0):

```
prstat -a
```

There's no need to capture a command's output with `$(...)` just to `echo` it back out. You can just run it directly.