# Create several named pipes (fifo) depending on input file content

Tags: python, perl, shell, awk, mkfifo

This [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) script splits one log file into some smaller files:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
/topic = / { topic = $NF }    
/ : / { print $3 >> topic "___" $1 }   # $1 is the field name
```

An input file example:

```
topic = foo
A   : 23
BB  : Text1
Zz  : 77

topic = bar
A   : 88
B   : 66

topic = foo
A   : 25
B   : 12
BB  : Text2
```

Example of generated output filenames:

```
foo___A
foo___B
foo___BB
foo___Zz
bar___A
bar___B
```

But now, I want to create output **fifo instead of regular file**.

The fifo (named pipe) should use the same filename as the current regular file. For example, one might write a shell script using the [mkfifo](/questions/tagged/mkfifo) tool as follows:

```
mkfifo foo___A
mkfifo foo___B
mkfifo foo___BB
mkfifo foo___Zz
mkfifo bar___A
mkfifo bar___B
```

common sense:

- the script should not be aware about all possible topics and fields
- the script does not require to create several times the same fifo

If [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is not suitable for this purpose, I am open to any other language as [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh), [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), [python](/questions/tagged/python), etc. ...

**What programming language would you choose to implement this script?** shell/awk/perl/python/ruby...
**What do you propose as implementation?**

---

EDIT: [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19546595/938111) is correct. There is also another alternative of his script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/topic = / { topic = $NF }    
/ : / { 
    file = topic "___" $1
    system("test ! -e "file" && mkfifo "file)
    print $3 > file
}
```

You can still propose your idea based on `awk` or any other programming language ;)

To test your script, you can run this below shell command in another terminal:

```
while true; do find -name '*___*' -ls -exec head '{}' '+'& sleep 1; done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/awk -f 

/topic = / { topic = $NF }    
/ : / { 
    file = topic "___" $1
    system("mkfifo "file)
    print $3 > file
    close(file)
    system("rm "file)
}
```

Keep in mind that the `print` will block until you read from the fifo, so you need to either background the awk command or read them from another terminal.

Comment: Hi Kevin. You are right `print` is blocked until pipe reading :( Any clue to use non-blocking named pipes? Cheers See you ;)

Comment: I have just found [this interesting answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/179469/938111) from [Charles Duffy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/14122) ... will try later ... Cheers