# What happens when the filesystem can't keep up with output from bash redirection?

Tags: bash, pipe

Say I have some process `my_proc` that generates output. I use `>` in bash to redirect that output to a file, like so:

`./my_proc > /some/file`

What happens when the file system can't keep up with the output from `my_proc` (i.e. `my_proc` is generating output faster than it can be written to disk)? I assume the file system will do some buffering, but what if it never catches up?

Is there a way to configure the maximum buffer size?

The optimal solution for me would be to just start dropping output if the buffer overflows (start redirecting to `/dev/null` or something). Is there an easy way to do that with bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no simple way of doing this in bash, but you can do it in C. But first, maybe you can get away with just writing every N lines? To write only every 100th line to a file, you can do:

```
slowprogram | sed -n '1~100p' > file
```

Anyways, let's do it with true non-blocking with a C snippet. Since at acts like a buffer but isn't really, we can be funny and call it `bluffer.c`:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int out;
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  int c;

  out = open("/dev/stdout", O_NONBLOCK | O_APPEND | O_WRONLY);

  while((c = read(0, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) != 0) {
      write(out, buffer, c);
  }
}
```

Now consider a command that quickly produces one million lines (~6.8MB) of data:

```
time printf "%s\n" {1..1000000} > /dev/null

real    0m1.278s
```

Now let's simulate slow IO by rate limiting it to 1MB/s with `pv`:

```
time printf "%s\n" {1..1000000} | pv -q -L 1M > slowfile

real    0m7.514s
```

As expected, it takes a lot longer, but `slowfile` contains all 1,000,000 lines.

Now let's insert our bluffer:

```
time printf "%s\n" {1..1000000} | ./bluffer | pv -q -L 1M > fastfile

real    0m1.972s
```

This time it's finishes quickly again, and `fastfile` contains just 141,960 of the 1,000,000 lines. In the file, we see gaps like this:

```
52076
52077
188042
188043
```

Comment: If I read this answer right, opening a named pipe in read-write mode implicitly set the O_NONBLOCK flag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179291/setting-up-pipelines-reading-from-named-pipes-without-blocking-in-bash.  I feel like this could be exploited to do what we want here in the shell, without having to resort to custom c programs, though for the life of me I can't yet figure out how

Comment: I'd be happy to hear anything useful for such approach. Sounds to me like somebody would be pulling hairs later reading the log, trying to understand what went wrong.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma It just says that opening in read+write mode will block on the read rather than the open call as for read-only.

Comment: @akostadinov We can only speculate. Maybe the program writes a ton of progress information which is nice to look at but not worth slowing down the system for by writing to a slow fbcon.

Answer (score 4):

Your app write calls will be delayed as long as file system catches up. Most probably net effect would be your app running slower waiting on the filesystem.

Write calls are usually buffered by the OS IO subsystem unless destination file is opened with appropriate flags. But this is not the case with stdout. File system can be mounted with appropriate options to disable buffering (i.e. sync mode) and that would avoid buffering but this is not usually done for performance reasons.

To get what you want, you would need to program your app to buffer output and discard buffer if it detects that filesystem is slowing you down. But it makes no sense. If you need the output, then you need to wait. If you don't need it, then it's better to not write it in the first place.

Comment: I think this is a good answer.  I added a pseudo-answer with an example to illustrate this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668127/what-happens-when-the-filesystem-cant-keep-up-with-output-from-bash-redirection/19668664#19668664

Answer (score 4):

I think @akostadinov's answer it right on the money.  This can be easily illustrated with a simple example:

```
$ time seq 1 1000000
1
2
...
999999
1e+06

real    0m40.817s
user    0m0.600s
sys     0m0.510s
$ time seq 1 1000000 > file.txt

real    0m0.556s
user    0m0.540s
sys     0m0.020s
$ time seq 1 1000000 > /dev/null

real    0m0.546s
user    0m0.540s
sys     0m0.000s
$
```

We use the `seq` utility to output numbers 1 to 1000000, and redirect the output to various places:

- With no redirection (output to stdout/terminal), `seq` runs many times slower
- Redirection to /dev/null and to a real file are fairly close, but significantly, for the /dev/null version, the "sys" component of the time taken is zero.